# What things would possibly indicate I should see a doctor about stomach worms?

Tags: infant

Age: 9 months.
What are the indicators that the infant needs a test for stomach worms?

Comment: try this: http://www.babycenter.in/a1050897/how-to-know-if-your-baby-has-worms

Comment: I very highly recommend seeking the advice of a Dr in regards to medical questions.  Us random people on the internet aren't the ones whom I would choose to put my daughter's health in the hands of... no matter how well-meaning we all are!

Comment: What makes you think your baby has stomach worms?

Comment: I think if the question was reworded to something like "What things would possibly indicate I should see a doctor about stomach worms", you might have something that's more acceptable to the site.  The question needs to be the sort of question you'd ask a fellow parent at the park, not something you'd normally ask your doctor.

Comment: @Joe I really like your comment about deciding an appropriate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I upvoted Jeremy's comment and I strongly believe you should see some neonatologist for the same. No risk should be taken if it's the problem of a baby.

Babies cannot express the pain or indications the like. The commonest thing they do is crying. Also, if the baby is infested with worms, we **may** see them in their stools. But smart little devil worms stick to the intestines and don't come out every time. Itchy bum is common but a 9-month-old may not express it.

Unusual crying, putting hands on stomach/abdomen and in some cases, increased appetite (because worms eat everything they eat!) **may be** the symptom.

I found this and think is useful.

> If your baby has a mild infection of threadworms, she may not show any symptoms. Check your baby’s bottom at night, after she has gone to bed. Gently part her buttocks and shine a torch around the opening of her bottom. If she has threadworms, you may be able to see one or more crawling out or around her pyjamas and bed sheets. You may also see threadworms in your baby’s stool.

Ever after all this, remember, see your pediatrician and don't rely on the Internet sources especially for the diagnosis and line of treatment. Internet may help you increase your knowledge about it and it should be used as a signaling tool than a doctor!